# LaunchAgent script can't write to external drive

Tags: python, bash, macos, launchd, macos-catalina

macOS Catalina

I have a python script that should write a file to an external drive. This works if I run the script manually. However, if the script is kicked off from a LaunchAgent bash script, it doesn't have permission to do so.

Simplified python script for example's sake:

```
with open('/Volumes/nas_1/test/somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                            the_file.write('Hello\n')
```

Bash script that the LaunchAgent kicks off located in `/Applications`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Start test script only if it is not running
if [ "$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep python_test.py | wc -l)" -le 0 ]
then

echo "Python Test Starting"
/Users/admin-user/.venvs/test/bin/python /Users/admin-user/projects/test/scripts/python_test.py

else
 echo "Python Test Already Running"
fi
```

**plist located in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.test.agent</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/runTest.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/runTest.stdout</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/runTest.stderr</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**Error:**

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Volumes/nas_1/test/somefile.txt'
```

I've given `/Volumes/nas_1/test` 777 permissions while debugging and that has not helped. Should I move the bash and or python scripts some where else?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with MacOS and here is a possible scenario with assumptions:
`LaunchAgent` or `launchd` runs with its own priviledge. Once you create `somefile.txt` with your
priviledge, `launchd` does not have the permission to open the file to append. Please remove the existing file and try again.

Comment: Same issue with the existing file removed and using `with open('/Volumes/nas_1/test/somefile.txt', 'w') as the_file:`. My real script creates a new file each time anyway. I provided that example for simplicity's sake since I see the same behavior creating a txt file and running my full script. macOS Catalina introduced some privacy protections for Launch Daemons & agents: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes. This script and LaunchAgent configuration worked prior to the Catalina update.

Comment: Sorry I was off the mark. BTW what happens if you change the destination to the internal drive?

Comment: Changing the destination to ‘~/Desktop’ works. If I can’t make this work, I’m going to have it write to a local directory and then have a cron move everything to the external drive every minute.

Comment: I cannot figure out what causes the difference but I suppose your workaround makes sense. Sorry for not being able to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have run into a similar problem. My bash script which copies files to an external drive via rsync fails to run after upgrading to Catalina.

The following is what I did to make it work again:

- Add `/bin/bash` in `System Preferences` / `Security & Privacy` / `Full Disk Access`
- Replace my shebang in the bash script with `/bin/bash` (was `/usr/bin/env bash`)
- Remove `StandardErrorPath` and `StandardOutPath` entries from my plist (Writing log files was denied because it was spawned as another process)

After that it starts to work again, maybe there are better solutions though.

Comment: +1000 I was using `zsh`, so I added `/bin/zsh` instead. I didn't have to remove the log files from my plist though, it still worked to have them in there (although the log file paths are in `/tmp` and not on the removable drive).